# C++ program not displaying the content from the text file correctly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

The program I'm writing is to suppose to list all payment made by each student, show amount paid and outstanding.

However the problem is that it not displaying correctly for some reason which I can't seem to find.

The payment.txt file content in the following order: 
Student Code  Amount   Type (blank means cash)

```
11  50
12  25  4543 2323 2321
12  25  Barclays
13  100 
14  100
15  50  4545 6343 4342
15  25  HSBC
16  100
17  100
18  100
19  100
20  25  4546 3432 3211
21  75
22  100 Lloyds
23  100
```

Here the is the code so far:

```
void payment()
{
    // Display message asking for the user input
    std::cout << "\nList all payment made by each student, show amount paid and outstanding." << std::endl;

    // Read from text file and Display list of payment

    std::ifstream infile;               // enable to open, read in and close a text file
    float StudentCode;                  // to store the student enrolment number
    float Amount;                       // to store the amount of money
    float Type;                         // to store information on type of payment made
    float Outstanding;                  // to store amount of money is due
    std::map<int, float> amountsPaid;   

    infile.open("Payment.txt");         // open a text file called Payment

    if (!infile)                 
    {
        std::cout << "List is empty" << std::endl;      // if the file is empty it output the message
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Display Headings and sub-headings
        std::cout << "\nList of Payment: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enrolment No." << "   " << "Amount" << "  " << "Outstanding" << std::endl;

        // accumulate amounts
        while (infile >> StudentCode >> Amount) 
        {
            amountsPaid[StudentCode] += Amount;
        }

        // loop through map and print all entries
        for (auto i = amountsPaid.begin(); i != amountsPaid.end(); ++i) 
        {
            float outstanding = 100 - i->second;
            // Display the list of payment made by each student
            std::cout << i->first << "      " << i->second << " " << "$: " << outstanding << '\n' << std::endl;
        }
    }

    infile.close();         // close the text file  
}
```

It display the following instead when it runs:

11    50   $50
12    25   $75
2321  12   $88
4543  2323 $-2223

Can you help explain why it doing this please?
Thanks

Comment: A simple fix  would be to put `infile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: @jrok You should explain why that works.

Comment: Some lines in your file contain data that you obviously don't want to read. It won't automagically go out of your way though, so: the statement in my previous comment tells the stream to ignore everything up to maximum stream size or the first new line character - whichever it encounters first. @DavidHeffernan provides alternative approach in his answer (a better one, since it's easier to check and handle possible erros, IMO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key section of code is here.

```
while (infile >> StudentCode >> Amount) 
{
    amountsPaid[StudentCode] += Amount;
}
```

This loop pulls of pairs of numbers. These are the pairs that get pulled off the stream:

```
11   50
12   25 
4543 2323 
2321 12
```

At that point the text `Barclays` is encountered and so the while loop terminates. That is because the text cannot be converted into a `float`.

To solve your problem you will need to switch to line oriented processing. Use `getline()` to pull off a line at a time. And then break the line into distinct items. One possible solution would be like so:

```
string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    istringstream strm(line);
    strm >> StudentCode >> Amount;
    amountsPaid[StudentCode] += Amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What your file contains is actually more than two columns and you are reading only two columns, so the next **infile >> StudentCode >> Amount** will read the type of payment as StudentCode. You should make only two columns in your file or discard further columns till end-of-line before reading next "StudentCode >> Amount" combination e.g.
while(infile >> StudentCode >> Amount)
{
    amountsPaid[StudentCode] += Amount;
    infile.getline(buff, size); // it'll read remaining line
}